# Custom Script not working after React Route change

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, scroll-position

I recently tried creating a dynamically styled Bootstrap 4 Navbar within React while exclusively using native Bootstrap 4 components and not having to rely on such things as react-bootstrap or reactstrap.

At first, this worked out rather well as I did not encounter any problems when I was using a script called ScrollPosStyler to create an "affix-top" navbar like in Bootstrap 3 which had a transparent background when at the top of the page and a dark background when scrolling across the page.

However, I wanted to natively use bg-dark and bg-transparent instead of the sps classes, so I created a listener based on the "attrchange" jQuery plugin which looked kind of like this:

```
$('nav.sps').each(function() {
  var elem = $(this);

  elem.attrchange({
    trackValues: true,
    callback: function(e) {
      if (e.attributeName == "class") {
          if (e.newValue.search("sps--abv") != -1) {
            elem.removeClass("bg-dark");
            elem.addClass("bg-transparent");
          } else if (e.newValue.search("sps--blw") != -1) {
            elem.removeClass("bg-transparent");
            elem.addClass("bg-dark");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });

});
```

However, I also tried implementing the same functionality for a light navbar that turns dark upon scrolling, and it was at this point that I encountered my main problem.

I added a function which took the "color" prop I assigned to each Navbar used in the various routes and added appropiate classes depending on the value of the prop, which looked very similar to this:

```
appropriateNavbarClass(props) {
    switch (props.color) {
        case "transparent":
            return "navbar-dark bg-transparent sps sps-t";
            break;
        case "light":
            return "navbar-light bg-light sps sps-l";
            break;
        case "dark":
        default:
            return "navbar-dark bg-dark";
            break;
    }
}

// and further down in render()
<nav class={"[standard navbar classes] " + this.appropriateNavbarClass(this.props)}>
```

The corresponding "sps-?" classes were then used to update my "attrchange" listener so it now added and removed *bg-transparent* **or** *bg-light* accordingly.

At first, I did not notice any problems with this code either, until I switched routes within the page: After switching, I would need to scroll down a bit and then all the way to the top of the page for ScrollPosStyler to pick up the newly rendered navbar element. I already tried manually initializing sps after a route update with `ScrollPosStyler.init();` but this unfortunately only resulted in "ScrollPosStyler is not defined" (Note: I tried this with all available syntaxes [es6 import, commonjs require, script tag at the bottom of the page], yet it never worked out in any way)

As always, If you need any additional code or information provided to answer the question, feel free to ask me and I will gladly do so. Also, I appreciate all suggestions for improving my code and or coding habits in general, for example for minifying my attrChange listener or simplifying navbar coloring.

Comment: do really you use class in nav or className? Besides of that, is your jquery running after the component did mount?

Comment: it's actually very easy to track the offset position with plain js, in your react component and set the appropriate state explicitly in your NavBar compononent to return the right class.

Comment: @webdeb I'm using standard HTML attributes as I have a webpack plugin which compiles them down to their JSX counterparts.

Comment: Also, the script shown above is executed within the "componentDidUpdate" of my main component, which is basically a container for all the different routes and components. This makes it easier for me to maintain individual navbars for each route.

Comment: The problem is, that you have two sources of truth like the component itself, and additionally with the jquery stuff. this is by definition not a good suite and those sideeffects from jquery may not work as expected. I would go with a react solution only. However, if you try that and you face some problems, you can open a thread for this.

Comment: From the docs: `
componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
`
try to use componentDidMount additionally